# add image with anchor center not work as expected

Tags: d3.js

Below code put image at (50,50), the anchor point is left top corner. How can I change the anchor point to image center, image dimension maybe changed, so if just change (50,50) to (0,0) will work for this image, but not work if image dimension changed.

I try add anchor to center but not work.

```js
var svg = d3.select('body')
.append('svg')
.attr('width',100)
.attr('height',100)
.style('border','1px solid red')
.attr('transform','translate(0,0)')

svg.append("image")
  .attr("xlink:href", "https://dummyimage.com/100x100/ececec/000000")
  .attr("x", 50)
  .attr("y", 50)
  .attr('anchor','center')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3@7.0.4/dist/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [MDN documentation for SVG Image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image), `image` has no `anchor` attribute. *After* the SVG is initially layed out, you could use get the size of the SVG and the size of the image and do it manually.  Something like so:

```
let s = d3.select(svg);
let svg_width = s.attr("width");
let svg_height = s.attr("height");

let img = s.select("image").node();
let rect = img.getBoundingClientRect();
let img_width = rect.right - rect.left;
let img_height = rect.bottom - rect.top;

img.setAttribute("x", (svg_width - img_width)/2)
img.setAttribute("y", (svg_height - img_height)/2)
```

Comment: why do this calculations "let img_width = rect.right - rect.left;" when the getBoundingClientRect() also gives you the width and height? rect.width, rect.height