# center and scale dynamic graph (<g>) in an <svg> element - d3

Tags: angular, d3.js

**What I want** is to center and scale a dynamically created graph in an svg element

**tl;dr:** I have an **svg** with fixed width and height, **1200x480**, and I have a ***dynamically created*** graph within a **g** element. The graph's width and height can be smaller or bigger than the available fixed size of the svg, so I will need to do some scaling as well as centering.
i.e. centering a graph with 330x250, is quite straightforward, the issues arise when either the width or height are bigger than the graph's

**More context:**
I have an svg, with a fixed width and height. The first node of the graph is drawn on **0,0** of the svg, and the rest follow a pattern of **length * dx** and **depth * dy**, to create the tree structure (you will notice in the images below the graph is in the negatives of the svg, this is because I want the graph to be read from right to left and I dont know the length or depth of the graph, I start from the parent on **0,0** and iterate through their children and create the graph)

**The fe code is simple:**

```
<svg id="svg" #svg [attr.viewBox]="0 + ', ' + 0 + ', ' + options.width + ', ' + options.height">
  <g id="decision-tree" [attr.transform]="'translate(' + centerX + ',' + centerY + ') scale(' + toScale + ')'">
    //graph elements go here
  </g>
</svg>
```

**The problem in pictures:**

a) If the height of the graph is bigger than the available size of the svg.
[image]

b) If the width of the graph is bigger than the available size of the svg.
[image]

c) both! are bigger than the available size of the svg

**What I tried:**

I tried several ways of calculating the new width or height of the graph but I think am missing something basic. Most along these lines:

```
widthLimit = 1200; heightLimit = 480;
let ratio = graphWidth / graphHeight;
newHeight = ratio / widthLimit;
scale = newHeight / graphHeight; //no idea if this is correct but it kinda worked
if(newHeight > heightLimit ) {
   newWidth = ratio * heightLimit;
   scale = newWidth / graphWidth; //no idea if this is correct but it kinda worked
}
```

This kinda worked in the length issue but never in the depth, and completely sucked if both were bigger

What am I missing? Is there a magic function in d3 that just does this? (please say yes ;D)
Whats the core logic I dont get?

Comment: You probably need to use [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect), which is a method of all HTML elements (including SVG). The tricky thing is that the element must be rendered in the DOM before it will work. Thus, you've got to render the whole thing, *then* modify it to get what you want. Might seem odd but, in practice, only the final stage is visible to the user.

Comment: yeah the problem are the maths. I was using getBBox to get the dimensions and details, I will use getBoundingClientRect and check it out, thanks

Comment: I actually answered a very similar question shortly before posting my comment here. That one was simpler to answer, since the OP posted code. Perhaps, [the code for that response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74491847/) will help. The math is not too hard; just a couple of subtractions and divisions by two.

Comment: indeed if the graph/g element is smaller than the available size of the svg its easy, for some reason I have the exact math with your answer and if the g element is bigger either in height or width its not working as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to come to a solution, I was missing some svg basics

- you need to set svg's `width`, `height` and `viewbox`
- before any translation translate the element to `0,0`, and set its scale to 1 `element.attr('transform', 'scale(1)');`

and the steps to center any sized element in an svg

1. **get the width and height** with d3's (of both the svg and the element you want to center) `getBoundingClientRect()`, i.e. for svg: `d3.select('#svg').node().getBoundingClientRect().width` and `.height;`
2. **find the scale factor**, divide `svgWidth/elementWidth` and `svgHeight/elementHeight`, and use the smallest of the two
3. **find x and y** using `(svgWidth - elementScaledWidth) / 2` and `(svgHeight - elementScaledHeight) / 2`
4. **do the translation** with d3's `element.attr('transform', 'translate(${x}, ${y}) scale(${scale})');`
5. **reset the `zoomIdentity`** of the svg with d3's `d3.select('#svg').call(d3.zoom().transform, d3.zoomIdentity.translate(x, y).scale(scale))`